# Simple IF() Formula No Longer Works

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

Has Microsoft pushed out a crummy update?

```
=IF(A1="",B1,A1)
```

no longer works.  I get the pop-up:

here is a problem with this formula.
Not trying to type a formula?
When the first character is an equal (=) or minus (-) sign, Excel thinks it's a formula:

- you type: =1+1, cell shows:  2

To get around this, type an apostrophe (') first:

- you type:  '=1+1, cell shows: =1+1*

Cell/column is of General format, not text.

Comment: What's version of Office you're using? Could you provide a screenshot about your problem cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your regional settings are using the comma as the list separator. That error will come up when you enter a comma instead of a semicolon. Typically, European countries use the semicolon in formulas instead of the comma.

```
=if(a1="";b1;a1)
```

The easiest way to figure out what to use on that computer is to build the formula with the ribbon commands. Click Formulas > Logical > IF. Fill in the condition and the other two boxes and see the formula being built correctly in the formula bar.

In my case, it's the comma. What does your system show?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are indeed right.  Earlier today I noticed that other spots that should have had commas had the pipes instead.  I had made the regional change to facilitate a csv export that had commas in the data.  Thanks again!...Neil

Comment: if that solves your problem, please finish the paperwork and mark the answer as described in the [tour].

Comment: BTW, there are ways to work with CSVs that don't require you to change your system settings, just to accommodate a file you want to import.

Comment: This was for an export to Access.  But still, care to elaborate?